# Different values for these two rounding expressions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

```
SELECT
ROUND(152.7300, 2, 1), --returns 152.7300
ROUND('152.7300', 2, 1) --returns 152.72
```

Why does the second rounding expression result in downward rounding to .72 ?

I imagine it has something to do with the `VARCHAR` input being converted to a `numeric`, but I can't imagine how that would cause it to lose a `decimal` value like that.

Comment: Did you mean `152.72` in the second `round` expression?

Comment: @CrazyCucumber - Yes, thanks.  I updated the question to reflect the correct returned value of 152.72.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass a string literal to `ROUND`, SQL Server converts it to `float`<sup>*</sup>. In contrast, [`152.7300` is treated as `numeric`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> In Transact-SQL statements, a constant with a decimal point is automatically converted into a numeric data value, using the minimum precision and scale necessary.

Exact `float` representation of `152.73` is `152.72999572753906`, hence truncation<sup>**</sup> to the second decimal digit yields `152.72`.

<sup>*</sup> You can check this by passing a non-numeric string, e.g. `ROUND('foo', 2, 1)`. This will produce "Error converting data type `varchar` to `float`."

<sup>**</sup> Passing a value other than zero for the third parameter of `ROUND` indicates truncation of the number, instead of rounding.

Comment: Can also be tested by adding digits to the length like `SELECT
ROUND(152.7300, 6, 1),
ROUND('152.7300', 6, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql

ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )

function
 Is the type of operation to perform. function must be tinyint, smallint, or int. When function is omitted or has a value of 0 (default), numeric_expression is rounded. When a value other than 0 is specified, numeric_expression is truncated.

Comment: This only partially answers the question. The function argument is not why the string value is being implicitly converted to float and *then* truncated. But it does describe why ROUND is truncating instead of rounding. I think maybe OP knew that already though and wants to know why it's not truncated to 152.73.

Comment: Yes, Dasblinkenlight's answer is a much better explaination than my lazy cut and paste from ms docs.